# How do I save multiple values and extra and use them in Sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables e.g.

**First table**

> ## ID   Value
>
> ### 1    Apple
>
> ### 2    Orange
>
> ### 3    Banana## ...

**Second Table**

> ## PERSON  FRUIT
>
> ### Amy     1
>
> ### Peter   2
>
> ### Charlie 1,2
>
> ### Dick    2,3

I would like to for example save what fruits the users have in just one column. So that when I call out what Charlie wants, I can somehow receive and output of Apple, Orange; and for Dick - Orange, Banana etc.

I am not really sure where to start on achieving this. Is it possible to do it purely in an SQL select statement alone?

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a link table. For example.. you have a Fruit Table, which stores all the unique fruits, and you have a Person table that stores all unique people.

So you should create a third table that links unique fruits to people for example...

```
ID      FRUIT      PERSON
 1        1           1
 2        1           2 
 3        2           1
```

etc... then a select on the link table with the person ID, would bring up all the fruits that person likes.

Comment: I see, I was trying to avoid something like that as I did not want to create too many tables. Seems like I've no choice?

Comment: I can't give you a definitive answer on whether or not there's another choice but...

Besides storing the fruit ID like an array within a column inside person called "Fruits", and doing a select statement on Person's where there is the fruit ID text within the array I don't see another way. However this way is pretty hack... other than that I could be wrong but I don't see another way since the Person, and Fruit table are both unique tables (the contents are all unique).